# Case issues with a redirect and regex

Tags: regex, wordpress, redirect

I have learned about using `(?i)` to ignore case in finding a word as a match in a URL. That works fine. But this issue is different.

I have this URL:

```
https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/public_talks/HelpOnline/source/ASSIGN.HTM
```

It should be:

```
https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/public_talks/helponline/source/assign.htm
```

So basically I am trying to do three things here:

1. Locate all `https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/public_talks/HelpOnline/source/*` links.
2. Force `helponline` to lowercase
3. Force the `*` value to **lowercase**.
4. So redirect becomes `https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/public_talks/HelpOnline/source/LOWER-CASE-OF-*`

Can I do this with the Wordpress 301 Redirection plugin using regex?

## Update 1

At the moment I have got this far:

Source: `/msa/(?i)helponline/(.*)$`
Target: `https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/msa/helponline/$1`

That caters for the `helponline` side of things by ignoring the case. But what about the last wildcard, referred to as `$` in the target? I need to force that to lowercase.

## Update 2

I tried to use `\L$1` to force the last token to lowercase but that didn't seem to work either. #confused

## Update 3

I tried the first answer and it seems to blow up the redirect. Could be a plugin issue. Then thing is I am using braces so I already have a group defined.  So I don’t understand why I can’t prefix $1 with the annotation. I might try the same using htaccess file instead.

Answer (score 0):

To use `\L$1`, you need to define a group so instead of your regular expression not being contained between `()`, it should be. Look at the following [**demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/cvMXsr/1)

Result for

```
https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/public_talks/HelpOnline/source/ASSIGN.HTM
```

is

```
https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/public_talks/helponline/source/assign.htm
```

---

### Picture

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I have just looked at the demo you provided but it is a lot of information. Can you please isolate as I do not see `L$1` there.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I thought you could see the `Substitution` part of the screen. I'll provide a print screen

Comment: Yes, I see that. But this IDE is new to me. Are you suggesting that I wrap the source url with the `(` and `)` characters and then I can use `\L$1` with the target link?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle You mean the group I created within the regex? I just encapsulated everything in between braces.

Comment: I got: `(?i)(/public_talks/helponline/(.*))$` and `https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/public_talks/helponline/\L$1`. That right?

Comment: I think it should work indeed. Have you tried it? I'm not familiar with Wordpress

Comment: It goes wrong - repeated `public_talks/helponline/L/public_talks/helponline/L/public_talks`

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I'm sorry Andrew, I don't have enough knowledge to help you further. Hope you'll find a solution from someone else.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred method is redirecting to lowercase URIs via httpd.conf settings:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

---

To redirect your specific URLs to lowercase you have to follow the same approach using a RuleMap like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/public_talks/HelpOnline/source/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

`\L` won't work. It's not supported by Apache/mod_rewrite.

Comment: But won't this change all url values to lowercase in the site? I have valid uppercase characters in my download filenames which need to stay as they are.